# Find the feet of perpendiculars on a plane

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

Perpendiculars are drawn from points on the line $\frac{x+2}{2}=\frac{y+1}{-1}=\frac{z}{3}$ to the plane $x+y+z=3$. The feet of perpendiculars lie on the line
$(A)\quad\cfrac{x}{5}=\cfrac{y-1}{8}=\cfrac{z-2}{-13}\hspace{1cm}$
$(B)\quad\cfrac{x}{2}=\cfrac{y-1}{3}=\cfrac{z-2}{-5}\hspace{1cm}$
$(C)\quad\cfrac{x}{4}=\cfrac{y-1}{3}=\cfrac{z-2}{-7}\hspace{1cm}$
$(D)\quad\cfrac{x}{2}=\cfrac{y-1}{-7}=\cfrac{z-2}{5}$

---

I have no idea how to solve this question. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Is it just me or are all the options the same?

Comment: @Gummybears,I am very sorry,i edited the question.

Comment: @diya Well I have no idea what to do as at the moment it isn't even a __question__

Comment: @BLAZE,Why are you saying so,sir?

Comment: @diya I'm sorry, but I simply have no idea what you're asking, solve _what_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Firstly, you find the plane which contains the line and orthogonal the plane.

After that, you can compute the intersection between two planes.